# Is it possible to implement custom file system adapter for state backend?

Tags: apache-flink

Is it possible to implement custom file system adapter for state backend?

Seems like I can implement own file system adapter base on [FileSystem](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/core/fs/FileSystem.java) but how to start using it in my flow for state backend?

Comment: Which file system would you like to use with the state backend?

Comment: I am thinking about Riak CS or Cassandra for store state.

Comment: Mh. Apparently you can access Riak CS with the S3 impl of Hadoop.
I'm not sure about using Cassandra as a FS back end. The state backend is going to put a lot of pressure onto cassandra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases you don't need to implement a custom file system implementation because Flink supports all file systems supported by Hadoop's `FileSystem` interface.

Comment: You are right. I have [found a way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36646111/2398521) how to join Apache Flink and Riak CS through Hadoop FileSystem interface. Thank you!